# selecting the rows from db based on date

Tags: mysql, php

I have a list of row's in mysql tables

```
+--------+-----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
| off_id | uid | leave_from | leave_to   | leave_code | reason    |
+--------+-----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
|      1 |   1 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-05 | OFF        | asdsda    |
|      2 |   1 | 2012-01-15 | 2012-01-16 | OFF        | asdd      |
|      5 |   1 | 2012-02-03 | 2012-02-05 | OFF        | gfjghjhgj |
+--------+-----+------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

I have to select the rows that are in between the date  2012-01-01 to 2012-01-05.
How can i do this please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Off_Id,uid,Leave_from,leave_to,leave_code
FROM YourTableName
WHERE Leave_From>="2012-01-01" and Leave_to <="2012-01-05"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE leave_from >= '2012-01-01'
AND leave_to <= '2012-01-05'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where leave_from between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-05'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE leave_from >= "2012-01-01" AND leave_to <= "2012-01-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

point 1 : you could use > < <= >= with date datatypes .

the above can be achieved by

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE leave_from > '2012-01-01' AND leave_from <'2012-01-05';
```